# Does scipy's interp1d works for non monotonic series?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have a series of X and Y values
The X values are not monotonic

When I apply numpy's interp it gives widely incorrect anwers (as it should since interp is guaranteed only for increasingly monotonic series of x)

However when I apply scipy's interp1d it works well

The documentation says

> If the values in x are not unique, the resulting behavior is undefined
> and specific to the choice of kind, i.e., changing kind will change
> the behavior for duplicates.

I can understand that, but that doesn't mean that for non monotonic increasing series if we interpolate a point where X are unique it wont work.
Does scipy's interp1d have some guarantee on this?

EDIT:
Just to clarify the X values are something like

```
91.18,91.12,95.8, 4.04,6.8,.......,87.1,91.18
```

So there is one pair of repeated xs, the order is not increasingly monotonic and the first three values are in disorder but after that they are ordered.

Comment: Well, ```interp1d``` has to do a binary search to find the neighbouring X and Y values. And it will not spend time checking more neighbours. So if you have duplicate but properly sorted X values, it might fall between two identical values or at the edge to a different X+Y pair. Obviously this changes linear interpolation

Comment: From your description I'm also still a bit confused. When you say, the X values are not monotonic, do you mean they are just not sorted? Because ```interp1d``` will simply do that. Otherwise its argument ```assume_sorted``` to suppress that operation does not make sense

Comment: @Homer512 mm interesting. I didn't know `interp1d` does a search for neighbors. I just did that by my own too. No wonder the results were identical